# what I'm missing in my code

Tags: flash-cs6

hi mi sorta brand new to this so the code is very simple I'm not very tech savy with coding also so if anyone does have an answer please speak in the dumbest terms you can for my benefit thanks sooooo much

the problem is it keeps telling me expecting semicolon before up and expecting identifier before semicolon any ideas ??

```
package  
{

    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.ui.*;



    public class Assignment2 extends MovieClip 
    {


        public function Assignment2() 
        public var character:Miner; 
        public var LEFT:Boolean;
        public var RIGHT:Boolean;
        public var APRESSED:Boolean;
        public var powerup:Boolean;

        {
            character = new Miner();
            addChild(character);    

            character.x = 150;      
            character.y = 150;      

            character.stop();

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onEnter);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,onKeyPress);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,onKeyRelease);
        }

        public function onEnter(e:Event)
        {
            //handle the animation of the game
            if(LEFT)
            {
                //do something for the left press
                character.x += -3
                character.gotoAndStop("walk");

                if(character.scaleX > 0)
                {
                    character.scaleX = -character.scaleX;   
                } 

            }

            if(RIGHT)
            {
                //do something for the right press
                character.x += 3
                character.gotoAndStop("walk");

                if(character.scaleX < 0)
                {
                    character.scaleX = -character.scaleX;   
                } 
            }

            if(APRESSED)
            {
                attacking = true;
            }

            if(powerup)
            {
                character.gotoAndStop("powerup");

                if(character.powerup.currentFrame == character.attack_mc.totalFrames)
                {
                    powerup = false;
                }
            }

            if(!LEFT && !RIGHT && !powerup)
            {
                character.gotoAndStop("idle");
            }
        }

        public function onKeyPress(e:KeyboardEvent)
        {
            switch(e.keyCode)
            {
                case Keyboard.LEFT:
                    LEFT = true;
                    break;
                case Keyboard.RIGHT:
                    RIGHT = true;
                    break;
                case Keyboard.A:
                    APRESSED = true;
                    break;

            }
        }

        public function onKeyRelease(e:KeyboardEvent)
        {
            switch(e.keyCode)
            {
                case Keyboard.LEFT:
                    LEFT = false;
                    break;
                case Keyboard.RIGHT:
                    RIGHT = false;
                    break;
                case Keyboard.A:
                    APRESSED = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the exact text of the error, and what line causes it?

Comment: Please [edit] your post and make the title more meaningful. Future readers searching for a solution to a problem with Flash are not going to find "what I'm missing in my code" very useful in the search results. Your title should be specific to the problem you're having and actually mean something. (While you're at it, you can add the specific error message you're getting, and the line of code where it's happening. You have those details right in front of you, and there's no reason for you not to share it with us.) Thanks.